# What best way i can add more events to this span using the conditional operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code

```html
<span
  role="link"
  tabindex="0"
  :class="tabDetails.showPayment ? 'link' : ''" 
  @click="tabDetails.showPayment ? cTab('payments') : null"
>
```

i also want to add the `keyup@enter` and `keyup@space` events to it, i am not sure how can i do it, any clues or idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its should be like this:

```
<span
    role="link"
    tabindex="0"
    :class="tabDetails.showPayment ? 'link' : ''" 
    @click="tabDetails.showPayment ? cTab('payments') : null"

    @keyup.click="clickMethod"
    @keyup.space="spaceMethod"
>...</span>

new Vue({
    ...
    clickMethod() {

    },
    spaceMethod() {

    }    
  }
})
```

Comment: and what those two methods be, what i need to write in those

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, we have separate event handler for enter and space key pressed. Hence, No need to use ternary operator for that. You can simply achieve that by using `@keyup.enter` & `@keyup.space`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    onEnterKeyPressed() {
      // You can put your logic here
        console.log('Enter Key Pressed');
    },
    onSpaceKeyPressed() {
      // You can put your logic here
        console.log('Space Key Pressed');
    }    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span
  role="link"
  tabindex="0"
  @keyup.enter="onEnterKeyPressed"
  @keyup.space="onSpaceKeyPressed"
  >{{ message }}</span>
</div>
```